# gem ancestry one person with 2 parents

Tags: ruby, rubygems, tree

When using [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) how could we generate a node with 2 parents (father, mother) at the same level ?
In case of multiple levels of parent what is the content of ancestry column  ?

Thanks for your help.

Pierre

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple levels of parent"?

Comment: Anyone have an idea on how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible or planed as a feature at the moment.

See "[Multiple tree structures with a common root](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/issues/94)".